# jquery noob problem with variables (scope?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve data from a php file named return that just contains

```
<?php
echo 'here is a string';
?>
```

I'm doing this through an html file containing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
  var x;
  $.get("return.php", function(data){
   x = data;
 }) 
 function showAlert() {alert(x);}

  $(document).ready(function(){
   alert(x);
 });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type = "button" value = "Click here" onClick="showAlert();">
</body>

</html>
```

When the button is clicked it retrieves and displays the code fine, but on the $(document).ready thing, it displays "undefined" instead of the data in return.php. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the document.ready is running before the $.get has returned the msg probably

```
var x;
function showAlert() {alert(x);}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get("return.php", function(data){
      x = data;
      showAlert();
   }) 
});
```

that should work fine

Answer (score 2):

The ajax probably has not loaded yet.

```
 var x;

 function showAlert() {alert(x);}

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.get("return.php", function(data){
    x = data;
    alert(x);
  }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a question of scope, it's a question of order of events.  `$.get` is an asynchronous call, so it may not finish yet by the time your page loads in the browser (it's a fairly small page so I imagine it loads quite quickly).